# Swift, Core Data. Переместил 2 файла описывающие объект в другую папку и появилась ошибка

Tags: ios, swift, entity, coredata

Все привет!
Пытаюсь внедрить Core Data в проект, создал сущность ArticleEntity, настроил запись и просмотр  объектов, всё работало. Потом решил переместить файлы объекта ArticleEntity в другую папку, в итоге вылезла ошибка и не мог зайди в файл CoreData, после чего я удалил файл CoreData и создал его заново, теперь не могу сохранить и посмотреть объект, хотя все названия сходятся. В codegen стоит Manual/None.
В чем может быть проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему. Все было на много проще чем я думал, когда я создал заново файл CoreData, у файла изменилось название и оно не совпадало с названием в AppDelegate в методе persistentContainer.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]